# rails select option styling with bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a select option in my rails application:

```
<%= f.select :willingToRelocate, ['Yes', 'No'] %>
```

It works fine, now I'm trying to style it with bootstrap, but can't get style to work.

This is whats on the bootstrap guide:

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

And heres a link to the bootstrap styling doc: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could style it like this `<%= f.select :willingToRelocate, ['Yes', 'No'], {}, class: 'form-control'} %>`

You could check out [this link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select). The api.rubyonrails have a great amount of information that you could use for these kind of problems.